# Json multiple array structure

Tags: php, arrays, json

For a system I need to create a select element with different options.
Because PHP and JavaScript can build this select element I thought it was a good way to use a json structure.
Both languages can use this to build the select element with the options.

The result that I want below

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 3">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    
</select>
```

Below my json code with PHP with a simple output

```
<?php
$json = '
{
    "Group 1": [
        { 
            "Option 1", 
            "Option 2", 
            "Option 3"
        },
    ],
    
    "Group 2": [
        { 
            "Option 1", 
            "Option 2", 
            "Option 3"
        },
    ],  
    
    "Group 3": [
        { 
            "Option 1", 
            "Option 2", 
            "Option 3"
        },
    ],
}';

$options = json_decode($json, true);

//get raw data
print_r($options);
?>
```

Unfortunately the print from PHP is empty.
Is there something wrong with my json structure?

Comment: Go to for example https://jsonlint.com/ and paste your data structure, then press `Validate JSON` If you run `var_dump($options);` you will see `NULL`, if you run `echo json_last_error_msg();` you will see `Syntax error`

Comment: When you go from PHP to JavaScript, you would normally _encode_ a higher level object to the JSON interchange format, I don’t know why you’d build a free form string and run _decode_ on it

Comment: It only makes sense to use JSON if you intend to push out the JSON to Javascript and let JS build the HTML tags in the browser. Otherwise, just have a regular PHP array and loop over that, generating the HTML. (N.B. Your JSON is "multi-invalid" and the decoding surely fails.)